# Best way to pass MPU6050 sensor data at 100 Hz from Edison to Intel Compute Stick

Tags: json, mqtt, iot, intel-edison

Our setup is:

1. Intel Edison reads raw data from MPU6050 at 100Hz and calibrates
2. Intel Compute Stick needs to read this data from Edison. Its connected with USB.

We need to ensure there is no lag as the data needs to be plotted in real time.

To pass data from Edison to Intel Compute Stick we are considering using MQTT but there is an opinion that it may lag due to some internal queue system.

Another option we are looking at is JSON, which could be also cause lagging at 100 readings per second.

Any advise on best protocol to use to communicate the info from Edison boars would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried soldering it?

Comment: sorry, soldering what?

Comment: JSON is a data format, MQTT is a network protocol, the 2 are totally un comparable.